# can any one help to parse perticular row and columns from xlsx format file and rereturn in another xlsx file

Tags: perl

I am trying to parse `1st` and `7th` column from `xlsx` file, and I want to rewrite that parsed columns to another new `xlsx` format file as the output.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use constant FILE_NAME => 'file1.xls';
my $workbook = ReadData ("Next seq_Run039_ Data Transfer     sheet_22.1.2015.xlsx");

$workbook = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new(FILE_NAME)
|| die "could not create $!";
$workbook->compatibility_mode();

my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
#my $parser = $worksheet->"Next seq_Run039_ Data Transfer sheet_22.1.2015.xlsx";
$worksheet->write_col(0, 0,[[qw(Header)],[ qw(File_Version), 1 ],[], [qw(Data)], [qw(SampleID SampleName Index Index2)]]);
$worksheet->write_col( 5, 0,  [1 .. 100] );


$workbook->close() or die "Error closing file: $!";
```

My question is how to parse the data and print the same into another file?

Comment: Check cpan module `Spreadsheet::XLSX` to read data from `xlsx`.

Comment: i can read the data but i am facing problem for rewriting the data into another xlsx sheet

Comment: @serenesat `Spreadsheet::Read` uses `Spreadsheet::XLSX` underhood if it deals with `xlsx` file type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are like to do with those columns and where you want to place it but this code can give you clue.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;
use List::Util qw(max);

use constant FILE_IN   => 'Next seq_Run039_ Data Transfer     sheet_22.1.2015.xlsx';
use constant FILE_OUT  => 'file.xlsx';
use constant SHEET     => 1;
use constant COLS      => ( 1, 7 );
use constant SKIP_ROWS => 3;
use constant COL_SPACE => 0;

my $book = ReadData(FILE_IN);
my @cols = @{ $book->[SHEET]{cell} }[COLS];

# undef $book; # you can release rest of $book

# there is filler as 0. row so +1
# note splice is destructive to $book->[SHEET]{cell} }[COLS] content but not to FILE_IN
splice @$_, 0, SKIP_ROWS + 1 for @cols;
my $max_row = max map scalar @$_, @cols;

# replace any space in @cols content by single '_'
map s/\s+/_/g, @$_ for @cols;

# Create new Spreadsheet

my $workbook  = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new(FILE_OUT);
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

# add header
my @header = (
    [qw(Header)], [ qw(File_Version), 1 ],
    [], [qw(Data)], [qw(SampleID SampleName Index Index2)]
);
$worksheet->write_col( 0, 0, \@header );

# insert columns from 3rd column
$worksheet->write( scalar @header,
    0, [ [ 1 .. $max_row ], ( [] ) x COL_SPACE, @cols ] );

$workbook->close();
```

Comment: error 

Undefined subroutine &main::ReadData called at t6.pl line 10.

Comment: sir its working , but how to extract data from 1st n 7th column?? kindly help me,

Comment: Mr.Henek i got one problem in the above code, the @cols is starting from 7th row of the sheet , i want it starts it from B5 th row, can u fix this problem?

Comment: You have to adjust `SKIP_ROWS` constant. You should set it to 3. It defines how many rows from the original file you would like to skip. You can as well adjust which columns you will transfer by setting `COLS` and also space between `1 .. $max_row` column and copied columns.

Comment: I have added flexible column spacer.

Comment: Thank u so much sir ,  and i have another query , i don't want any space in the parsed data can u suggest me how to tackle this ? i am trying to do so using $workbook =~ s/\r//g; line, but this is not working, kindly suggest me to do so

Comment: I don't know what space you are dealing with. Space in some field? Empty rows in original data? Empt row in header?

Comment: white space in the file.xlsx sheet

Comment: But where are they coming from?

Comment: inside the parsed data,

Comment: this command is not working ~ s/\s/""/g, can u help me please??

Comment: where ever whitespace is there, i want to remove those white space and replace it by _ (underscore),
is it possible to do so??

Comment: You should reaload in your browser.

Comment: sir is it possible to do this replacement for particular column, i.e if i want to replace whitespace to _(underscore) for only 2nd column , than what i have to change in the code?

Comment: `s/\s+/_/g for @{$cols[1]};`

Comment: this is removing all underscore from the file, to be specific, i want to replace whitespace with underscore for only B column, is it possible to do?

Comment: B column from original? There is only copied A and G column. If you mean B column in the result, it is first (A) colum in original so you have to use `s/\s+/_/g for @{$cols[0]};`

Comment: i parsed the data from 1st n 7th column but in output file i inserted those data in B column so in output file i wish to put _ only for B coloum